# How to add DANE/TLSA on a wildcard subdomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, tls, wildcard

I would like to enable DANE/TLSA on *.example.com for https.

To activate it on example.com I can do that (I used TYPE52 instead of TLSA because my DNS provider is not DANE-aware):

```
_443._tcp.example. IN TYPE52 # 35 01010102d50459538b4c549014266824948c9294da322581e51a0f0e79ce8aea0def89
```

Wildcard are not allowed in the middle so I can't do that (right?) :

```
_443._tcp.*.example. IN TYPE52 # 35 01010102d50459538b4c549014266824948c9294da322581e51a0f0e79ce8aea0def89
```

But activate it on *.example.com the only way I found is (the first line was already there to redirect *.example.com on the same IPs) :

```
*                         IN CNAME  example.com.
example.com.              IN TYPE52 # 35 01010102d50459538b4c549014266824948c9294da322581e51a0f0e79ce8aea0def89
```

It works but it falsely enable it for all protocols/ports (ssh, imaps, ...)

Did I miss something ?

Should I explicitly add all sub-domains instead of using a wildcard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you missed anything. At least not for a nameserver that serves static data, which is probably your only option anyway as you need DNSSEC.

In general, if it's feasible you probably should add the names that are actually in use rather than use wildcards. (It's clearly better from a technical perspective, however it's usually business demands that drive people to use wildcards.)

Comment: Thank you. I know I could manage my own DNS nameserver but I really don't want to manage the DNSSEC part! I think I'll remove the wildcard. And as the website doesn't has a wildcard certificate and has HSTS preload, inexistent subdomains are not accessible anyway.

Comment: I'd like to revisit this question. If I have a wildcard `*.domain TLSA` then it will be returned for any subdomain like `_443._tcp.RANDOMSUBDOMAIN.domain` because even though its three labels, it matches the wildcard. However, this TLSA doesn't validate and I suspect it its because the DNSSEC signs the `'*'` literally and perhaps this is not getting resolved properly.

Comment: @pinhead I'd think the problem rather is that `RANDOMSUBDOMAIN.domain` presumably exists, right? Which makes `*.domain` not match `RANDOMSUBDOMAIN.domain` (or for that matter `_443._tcp.RANDOMSUBDOMAIN.domain`). Wildcards only ever expand to names that do not exist (regardless of type).